# Enable Keyboard Type DecimalPad in Mobile Safari (via HTML)

Tags: html, ios, safari, keyboard

**Question:** Is it possible to trigger the keyboard type: **decimalPad** in a HTML form rendered within mobile safari (i.e. numeric keyboard with a decimal point)?

**Note:** While a "numeric" keyboard is possible by specifying `<input type="number" pattern="d\*" />` I have had no luck triggering a numeric keyboard with a decimal point. At this stage, it seems like this is only possible when building a native iOS application (as opposed to a web app).

**Apple Documentation:** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html

Answer (score 7):

Since iOS 12 the [inputmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) attribute is supported by Safari (and by the WebView)

See here for browser support: https://caniuse.com/input-inputmode

```html
<input type="number" pattern="\d*" inputmode="decimal"/>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Note that if you only need numerals (and the negation symbol on some browsers), you can alternatively use `inputmode="numeric"`.